# grub menu after failed installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, cuda

After my graphics driver was probably damaged during a failing cuda installation, I tried to reinstall Ubuntu. The instalation went ok - the menu suggested to erase and reinstall which i did and it ended with a "installation complete".

Then I restarted the computer and a black screen appeared with the following text:

> ```
> GNU grub version2.02 beta2-36ubuntu3.6
>
> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported for the first word TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions"
> ```

What is this menu? how can I pass it? does it mean the instalation failed? by the way, I've dissabled the UEFI.

Comment: Can you write down the message you get and [edit] your post with it instead of uploading a picture? Would be much easier to read.

Comment: @M.Becerra i've edited

Comment: You probably get better results with UEFI in all UEFI enabled machines. Ubuntu seems to be the only OS you want/have, what's the point in installing in Legacy/CSM mode when you don't need to? Also, if you were installing CUDA you have a Nvidia graphics that may not have proper support from the default open-source driver so you use `nomodeset` as a boot parameter during the installation and until you install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I also have a Windows 10 on my computers, and it works fine. I want to have bot Win10 and ubuntu. I've installed on legacy following an advice, after my cuda installation failed and the graphics crashed.

how do I use `nomodeset`? I install from a usb disk. Shouldn't ubuntu be alreadt compatible with nvidia?

Comment: When I install ubuntu for the first timw it worked just fine. Only after the CUDA instalation things started to crash. How can I go back to that state?